# How to reference image source files that are packaged with my metro style app?

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have a .png file as a content of my application. When I bind it in xaml like this

```
<ImageBrush x:Key="BtnBackImageBrush" ImageSource="/Assets/Images/back.png" />
```

everything ok.

I read [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.controls.image.source.aspx) and when I try to get access to this .png programmatically I get an error.

Code I use:

```
Uri baseUri = new Uri("ms:appx");
Image img = new Image();
img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(baseUri, "/Assets/Images/back.png"));
img.ImageFailed += (sender, args) => new MessageDialog("Error").ShowAsync();
```

And my question is how to reference image source files that are packaged with my metro style app?

Thanks for advices.

**UPDATE:**
I found answer!
We need set baseUri using parent FrameworkElement instead of setting it manually. For example:

```
// Usage
myImage.Source = ImageFromRelativePath(this, "relative_path_to_file_make_sure_build_set_to_content");

public static BitmapImage ImageFromRelativePath(FrameworkElement parent, string path)
{
    var uri = new Uri(parent.BaseUri, path);
    BitmapImage result = new BitmapImage();
    result.UriSource = uri;
    return result;
}
```

Thanks for this [article](http://www.codingbeta.com/programatically-setting-image-source-in-metro-style-apps-with-wpf/).

Answer (score 9):

> new Uri("ms:appx");

I think that's the source of the original problem. The scheme is ms-appx not ms:appx

Bad URI: `ms:appx://Assets/Images/back.png`
Good URI: `ms-appx://Assets/Images/back.png`

But using FrameworkElement is not a bad idea, if you're really trying to scope something like its parent - even if both work, the latter is probably may be clearer to the reader of your intent (assuming that's your intent).

Comment: Should be ms-appx:///      note the 3 /

Answer (score 6):

Yes you are right, this is the answer to your question.

```
img.Source = ImageFromRelativePath(this, "Assets/Images/back.png");

public static BitmapImage ImageFromRelativePath(FrameworkElement parent, string path)
{
    var uri = new Uri(parent.BaseUri, path);
    BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
    bmp.UriSource = uri;
    return bmp;
}
```